# How to animated state change of blurView in Cocoa?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am making my blurView with this code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let blurView = NSVisualEffectView()
        blurView.blendingMode = .behindWindow
        blurView.material = .popover
        blurView.state = .followsWindowActiveState
        
        self.view = blurView
        
    }

}
```

This codes allow me blur effect when window is active and it disables blur effect when window los the key window, I want make this transition with animation, currently the changing state of blurView is without animation.

How to animate `blurView.state = .followsWindowActiveState` when window get or los the key position?